# Books on Statistics in R for behavioral data analysis

Tags: methodology, statistics, language

Are there any statistics books geared towards teaching behavioral data analysis especially in psycholinguistics?

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a few other options that I consider relevant:

-[Longitudinal Data Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences Using R](https://us.sagepub.com/en-us/nam/longitudinal-data-analysis-for-the-behavioral-sciences-using-r/book234770)

-[Behavioral Research Data Analysis with R](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781461412373)

-[Methods for the Behavioral, Educational, and Social Sciences: An R package](https://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/BF03192993) (an interesting paper).

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of resources out there for learning R and many of the general ones are useful for people in psychology.

For example, see the R contributed documentation:
https://cran.r-project.org/other-docs.html

I really like the Quick-R site:
https://www.statmethods.net/

That said, in terms of psychology-specific resources, check out:

- Personality Project R Guide: http://personality-project.org/r/psych/

In terms of books that are psychology specific, here are a couple:

- *Learning Statistics with R*: https://learningstatisticswithr.com/ This book is available for free online thanks to Danielle Navarro's use of a CC-BY-SA licence.
- *Discovering Statistics Using R*. If you like Andy Field's accessible style, then you'll like this book.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the answer!